# Tag for JavaScript exists but it is off-topic on Super User

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about JavaScript on Super User and eventually deleted the question (as people voted to close and started downvoting). And for that matter, the question did not warrant an expert level answer (or comment).

My question now is, if such questions are off-topic, why have such tags on Super User in the first place?

*(P.S: I do not know if Stack Overflow came first or Super User came first. So if such questions were being answered on Super User in the beginning and the tag stays only to keep those older questions alive, pardon my ignorance.)*

Comment: Sometimes tags may not relate to the question content at all (that depends on the decision of the taggers) , I mean what is considered as off-topic is actually the question content.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Programming* in JavaScript may be off-topic but if your browser is having trouble running JavaScript, perhaps due to it having been disabled, then that would be on-topic here.

Programming languages are on-topic here so long as the question is not about actual programming. How to install PHP or similar would be on-topic, how to write something in PHP would not.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mokubai's answer:

Just because a tag doesn't exists here, it does not mean people will not ask questions related to it.

However to an existing tag we can add description showing the right direction, like for [javascript](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/javascript):

> JavaScript is a programming language. Programming questions are off topic here; ask on Stack Overflow instead.